# Populating more fields in function of specific elements in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

To populate a specific field in function of the telephonic prefix number of this table

```
 ___________________________________________________________
 |  id  |   telnum   |   name   |   country   |  continent |
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 |  01  | 003912377  |   Smith  |   Italy     |            |
 |  02  | 004412345  |   White  |    UK       |            |
 |  03  | 005454321  |   Lopez  |  Argentina  |            |
```

I use the following code:

```
UPDATE telcountry_table
SET country =
CASE 
   WHEN left(telnum,4) = 0093 THEN 'Afghanistan'
   WHEN left(telnum,5) = 00355 THEN 'Albania'
   WHEN left(telnum,5) = 00213 THEN 'Algeria'
   .
   .
   .
   ELSE ''
END
```

It works perfectly. My question now is: can i add also further lines in the same code to populate other fields, such as (in this example) the specific continent, or i have to make another different query?

**In few words my problem is: when the prefix is "0044" the code must write the element "UK" in the field Country, the element "EUROPE" in the field Continent... and so on.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your current data model is optimal/normalized and the reason the UPDATE is so puzzling. In order for the UPDATE to work, you would need a WHERE clause to filter  the "id" you wish to update; the result of the CASE statement, ex. id=02 when left(telnum,4) = 0044. To accomplish this, you will need to create a stored procedure (one solution is to  employ a cursor).

However, I would suggest an alternative normalized design something like the following:

I assume there can be many telnum prefixes (area codes) per country:

```
create table areacodes
(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  areacode varchar(10),
  fkCountry int
);
insert into areacodes(areacode,fkCountry)
values
('0039',1),('00441',2),('0054',3);

create table countries(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  country varchar(20)
 );
 insert into countries(country)
 values('Italy'),
 ('UK'),('Algeria');

 create table continents(
 id int auto_increment primary key,
 continent varchar(20));

 insert into continents(continent)
 values('Europe'),('North America'),('Asia'),
 ('Australia'),('Africa'),
 ('South America'), ('Antartica');
```

The following table associates countries with continents:

```
create table country_continent(
fkCountry int,
fkContinent int);

insert into country_continent(fkCountry,fkContinent)
values(1,3),(2,1),(3,5),(4,1),(5,1),(6,6)
```

Finally, the telcountry table. You will need to separate the areacode from the telnum and save them both. You can then retrieve the country and continent using the areacode.

```
create table telcountry_table(
  id int,
  areacode varchar(10),
  telnum varchar(20),
  name varchar (50)
);
insert into telcountry_table(id,areacode,telnum,name)
values
(1,'0039','234244','Di Maggio'),
(2,'00441','2345','White'),
(3,'0054','54321','Sergio');
```

You can find the country and continent as follows:

```
select country 
from areacodes a join countries c
on c.id = a.fkCountry
where areacode = '00441'
```

And continent:

```
select continent 
from country_continent cc join continents c
on cc.fkContinent = c.id
where cc.fkCountry =
(
select c.id 
from areacodes a join countries c
on c.id = a.fkCountry
where areacode = '00441'
)
```

Comment: How can this code write the right name of the continent? Do I need to re-write conditions "when - left - then" also for continent?

Comment: There is no need for the UPDATE statement at all when employing this data-model, which I recommend you take the time to understand for its educational value alone. It also eliminates data redundancy (3NF) and simplifies adding new area-codes and countrie.